# JQuery/ajax : Problem with jsonp call

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

I am trying to make a cross-site request, on a site that needs authentication. The authentication works with a cookie.

For some reason, when I am doing this call :

```
$.getJSON(url + '?', function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

I don't see the `Cookie` sent in the HTTP headers. While when I just copy paste `url` in my address bar, the call is successful, and `Cookie` is set properly...

I tried to replace the `$.getJSON` by a `$.ajax`, and set manually the request headers. It resulted in the request not even visible in firebug (while I know it has been sent and answered to by using another tool)!!!

I am using firefox 3.6, jquery 1.4

Any idea on what's going on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), JSONP requests to **other domains** will not have any cookies sent with them.